# Upload/Copy Virtual Box configuration to another machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have setup a Virtual Box on my computer_A. And I would like to use the same configuration settings on another computer_B.

a) How do I upload/share/copy a virtual box config file on/with another computer?

b) Where is the config files located?

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

if you did not give another path during installation, the Virtual Boxes are created under `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\...`

They consist of the configuration file named `<yourname>.VBOX` (where `<yourname>` is whatever you named your Virtual Box), and the corresponding 'hard disk' `<yourname>.VDI`.

If you copy those two files to a machine with matching architecture which has also VirtualBox installed, it will run right away there. Use Machine/Add in the VirtualBox and pick the *.VBOX you copied.

Note that by copying the Virtual Box, you get a second independent Virtual Machine, but you did not magically get a second license key for anything. Using the same license on two machines will technically work fine, but might or might not be allowed by your license agreement.